# ngroute with angular boostrapping

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-route

I was just trying to make the angular bootstrapping work where I want to get my app loaded only after retrieving some data from the server using the service call. However I am not able to make this work with the $routeprovider. My routes doesn't work after this bootstrapping. can anyone know what is wrong I am doing here???

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap',
        'dataHandler', 'underscore','ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar' ]);


fetchData();

function fetchData() {
    var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
    var $http = initInjector.get("$http");

    return $http.get("/path/to/data.json").then(function(response) {
        bootstrapApplication();
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        // Handle error case
        bootstrapApplication();
    });
}

function bootstrapApplication() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {


myApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        redirectTo : '/dashboard'
    }).when('/dashboard', {
        menuItem: 'DASHBOARD',
        templateUrl : '../views/customer/dashboard/customerDashboard.html',
        controller : 'CustomerDashboardControllerPT',
        controllerAs : 'custdashboard'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);




    angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
});
}
```

It seems it doesn't recognize my MainController also. In my html file I have code like:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController as main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="../frameworks/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="../frameworks/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../frameworks/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="../frameworks/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="../frameworks/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../frameworks/angular/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../frameworks/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../frameworks/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../frameworks/angular/loading-bar.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
```

Comment: you don't have an `ng-view` tag for the template to load into in this HTML.

Comment: let me create a plunker for this.

Comment: can use ui-router and get the data in resolve of the main app state. No need to do manual bootstrap that way